# What does ";1" mean at the end of my .zip file?

Tags: filenames, zip

I have received a zip file but the actual filename is

```
data.zip;1
```

I have tried to unzip on Linux 7.1 but the command fails. What does the `;1` at the end of the file mean?

Ran `file 'data.ZIP;'`. The results are as follows:

```
data.ZIP;1: regular file, no read permission
```

Comment: names are just names and aren't important. What's really important is the content of the file. Run `file data.zip;1` to see if it's a zip file or not

Comment: @phuclv `file 'data.zip;1'`, the filename must be quoted as `;` is a command terminator otherwise.

Comment: If "the command fails" then something went wrong. If you post the text here, we might  guess why.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes I forgot that. It may also be the reason the unzip command fails, but we'll have to wait until the OP shows the command he ran

Comment: ran the command. The results are as follows  data.ZIP;1: regular file, no read permission

Comment: @John edit the question and update everything there. No one will read comments. But if you can't read the file then it might be created with root permission. Show the output of `ls -l 'data.zip;1'` and run the command with `sudo`

Comment: `data.zip;1` or `data.ZIP;1`? Usually they should be different files as case is important

Comment: Does it work if you trp unzipping the file using `unzip 'data.ZIP;1'` (or `unzip 'data.zip;1'`, whatever the name of the file is)?

Comment: With a `;1`, that might be a VMS formatted file, which you cannot count on unzipping on a Unlx (or Linux) machine.  `zipinfo` as suggested will show whether that is the case.  (This is separate from the obvious answer to quote the zip filename).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a command `zipinfo` if you have `unzip`.

Try `zipinfo -2t 'data.ZIP;1'` or `zipinfo -2t 'data.zip;1'` (as appropriate)

This should output some thing like:-

```
Archive: data.ZIP;1
Zip file size: 1069878 bytes, number of entries: 999
filename1
filename2
...
999 files, 1727702 bytes uncompressed, 1060860 bytes compressed:  38.6%
```